# MapBox add interactive annotation/view at location iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, annotations, mapbox

I am trying to implement MapBox maps,special reason for using it, it is highly customizable, I need to create a different kind of map with all different colors, I got that working perfectly fine.

The problem I want to add annotation on map that should interactive from within, normally an annotation is interactive by just tapping on it, it works, I need something like a UIButton in the annotation and clicking on the Button action should perform.

**Question** 
   How to create an annotation with a button/view in MapBox, how should I approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

To Be more precise I want something like the image below [image] for annotation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to get this working finally. I have created a Subclassed RMMarker class in MapBox Project and I am adding all the components as CALayer, adding components in `UIView` then adding `UIView.layer` doesn't work. You have to add sublayers in the UIView layer.

Then I have created come custom delegates to handle the touch events.

Make sure you use MapBox from [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk) and add MyMarker inside the MapBox project as a component.

I am adding my code here

**MyMarker.h**

```
#import "RMMarker.h"

@interface MyMarker : RMMarker 
@end
```

**MyMarker.m**

```
@implementation MyMarker 
-(id)init{ 

    self=[super init]; 

    if(self){ 


       UIView *subLayer=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 126, 91)];



       UIView *smallView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36.0, 0, 88, 91)];

       //smallView.contents=(id)image;

       [subLayer.layer addSublayer:smallView.layer]; 

       subLayer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor]; 

       subLayer.layer.name=@"Annotation"; 

       [self addSublayer:smallView.layer]; 


        float y=11.0; 
        float x=12.0; 

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ 
           CGPoint pt=CGPointMake(x, y); 
           UIView *handle=[self createHandle:@"Handle" fromPos:pt]; 
           y=y+14.0; 
           handle.layer.name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handle at %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(pt)]; 
           [self addSublayer:handle.layer]; 
      } 
   } 

   return self; 
}

-(UIView *)createHandle:(NSString *)handle fromPos:(CGPoint)pos{

    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, 60.0, 5.0)]; 

    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor]; 


    return view; 


} 
@end
```

**RMMapViewDelegate.h**

`- (void)tapOnMarker:(MyMarker *)marker at:(CGPoint )pt;`

**RMMapView.m**

Added `BOOL _delegateHasMyMarkerDelegate;`

Setup Delegate method properties

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id <RMMapViewDelegate>)aDelegate{ 
     _delegateHasMyMarkerDelegate=[_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapOnMarker:at:)]; 
}

- (void)tapOnMarker:(MyMarker *)marker at:(CGPoint)aPoint 
{ 
    if (_delegateHasMyMarkerDelegate) 
   { 
        [_delegate tapOnMarker:marker at:aPoint]; 
   } 

}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{ 
    //Default initializers

     CALayer *superlayer = [hit superlayer];

    // See if tap was on an annotation layer or marker label and send delegate protocol method 
   //Added conditions for MyMarker touch events 
    if ([superlayer superlayer] != nil && [[superlayer superlayer] isKindOfClass:[MyMarker class]]){ 

         [self tapOnMarker:((MyMarker *)[superlayer superlayer]) at:[recognizer locationInView:self]]; 

}else if ([[superlayer superlayer] superlayer] != nil && [[[superlayer superlayer] superlayer] isKindOfClass:[MyMarker class]]){ 

        [self tapOnMarker:((MyMarker *)[[superlayer superlayer] superlayer]) at:[recognizer locationInView:self]]; 

}else if (superlayer != nil && [superlayer isKindOfClass:[MyMarker class]]){ 

        [self tapOnMarker:((MyMarker *)superlayer) at:[recognizer locationInView:self]]; 

   }

}
```

**Implementation**

```
-(RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation{

     if(annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation) 
         return nil;

    MyMarker *marker=[[MyMarker alloc] init]; 
    [marker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 126, 91)]; 


     return marker;

}

#pragma mark MyMarker Delegate

-(void)tapOnMarker:(MyMarker *)marker at:(CGPoint)pt{ 

    for (CALayer *layer in marker.sublayers) { 
        CGPoint convertedPt=[[marker superlayer] convertPoint:pt toLayer:layer]; 
        if([layer containsPoint:convertedPt]){ 
             NSLog(@"%@ selected",layer.name); 
        } 

    }

}
```

**Hope it helps someone, who want to create Marker/Annotation and want multiple actions over it.**

Comment: I was able to implement a similar approach with awesomeMenu but I will try this definitely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `- (void) singleTapOnMap:(RMMapView *)map at:(CGPoint)point` delegate? I don't see you use any button states, so seems to me the easiest way is:

```
func singleTapOnMap(map: RMMapView!, at point: CGPoint) {
        let layer = someObject.layer
        let frameOnScreen = layer.superlayer.convertRect(layer.frame, toLayer: map.layer)

        if CGRectContainsPoint(frameOnScreen, point) {
            NSLog("hit")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its quite old though, but you didn't read the requirement correctly I guess, using the above function will allow to select the whole annotation, my requirement was to design a single annotation with multiple actions in it, I will be happy you add more correct answer to it. Might be `MapBox` have improved with time, I am not following it from long. I had contributed my solution to MapBox, they too accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
func mapView(mapView: RMMapView!, didSelectAnnotation annotation: RMAnnotation!)
```

delegate method, and  do the stuff you wanted to do in the button tapped action.

Comment: NO, on didSelectAnnotation, the buttons appear. The buttons are added in the annotation.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question. But instead of adding the buttons in annotation, couldn't you just add them to the superview and layout them according to the annotation position? I assume that those buttons will show up for every annotation. This way you could have avoid the layers and stuff, *((MyMarker )[[superlayer superlayer] superlayer]* not good) and just implement the button actions in your view controller.  And you could get the point of annotation with: *self.mapView.coordinateToPixel(annotation.coordinate)*

Comment: NO, that too is not possible as MapBox uses CALayer for its implementations, not UIView, otherwise it would have been done like you said.

Comment: No I mean you could've just add the buttons to the superview of the mapbox. Which is definitaley have to be a UIView

Comment: Yes I understood, you are saying to add directly to the map, it might create layout problems if zoomed in/out, and I am not sure, though its a very old problem tried lots of things that time don't remember all, came up this solution of course, it can be optimized.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this example in the MapBox documentation: http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/callout-accessory-view/ This works very similarly to MapKit.

Comment: Thanks @incanus, but the above link doesn't solve my purpose.